# WCF CallBack + ASP .NET MVC. Session равно NULL

Tags: asp.net, wcf, storage

Есть двухстороний (dual binding) WCF сервис wsDualHttpBinding , на котором есть Callback интерфейс.

На ASP аппликации имплементирую этот интерфейс и вызываю в нужный момент.

Далее сервис вызывает этот метод в ASP. MVC аппликации.

```
 public void SendComment(ChatCommentContract cc)
 {
    Session["Message"] = cc;         
 }
```

Проблема в том, что в этот момент Session равняется NULL и выдает ошибку.

Вопрос, как можно сохранить данные в Сallback методе, что бы потом Controller мог использовать эти данные?

Comment: static dynamic Msg; static object Msg; Вам не подходит? создайте их в контроллере

Comment: @AiSatan Сейчас попробую. Идея такая, что есть много чат комнат. Надо что бы каждый пользователь, которые сидит в этой комнате, мог хранить все сообщения, что в комнате. Как я понимаю, если будет static object Msg, то со всех чат комнат приходящие сообщения будут хранится в этом обьекте.

Comment: Возможно тогда стоит использовать static Dictionary<имяКомнаты, сообщения[]>. статик нужен что бы не создавать экзепляр контроллера, но да, он для всех пользователей будет общий. Возможно понадобиться даже ConcurrentDictionary.